# Weird behavior of Cursor.retrieved

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Was trying to do a query and check if the returned Cursor was empty. Was getting very frustrated when, no matter whether my Cursor was empty or not, `.retrieved` would always return 0.

I discovered something strange: if I loop through the Cursor first, `.retrieved` returns correctly.

```
results = db.states.find({'name':'Bavaria'})
for result in results:
    print(result)
print(results.retrieved)
```

outputs:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('61ce793f2d4db12129390fae'), 'name': 'Bavaria', 'country_code': 'DE', 'code': 'BY'}
1
```

But move the loop:

```
results = db.states.find({'name':'Bavaria'})
print(results.retrieved)
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

and I get:

```
0
{'_id': ObjectId('61ce793f2d4db12129390fae'), 'name': 'Bavaria', 'country_code': 'DE', 'code': 'BY'}
```

So...what the heck?

Comment: What exactly were you expecting the `retrieved` property to be in these cases?  It seems to be working exactly as documented - in the first case you had looped over the single matching result, and in the second case you hadn't done anything yet, so the number of retrieved elements are 1 and 0 respectively.

Comment: "working exactly as documented" all it says in the documentation is "The number of documents retrieved so far." Am I supposed to extract from that sentence that I have to run a query and then loop over it before I can use it?

Comment: If you haven't run a query, then obviously no documents have been retrieved yet, and the value of this property will necessarily be zero. Again, *what value were you expecting*?  Perhaps one of the other properties/methods gives you the information you want - `.count()` looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comments, `.retrieved` will return the number of documents so far retrieved from the cursor.

If you want to check if your query returns "empty" or not, it might be as easy to perform a `find_one()` with the same filters first; if this returns `None`, then there's no match. Of course if you only care if there are zero or one matches, then `find_one()` is easier than a `find()`

If you don't like to make two calls, then use a `next()` to inspect the first value in a try..exception. You will need to rewind the cursor before iterating to make sure you still get all the records, e.g. something like:

```
try:
    next(cursor)
    cursor.rewind()
except StopIteration:
    print('No matches')

for item in cursor:
    print(item)
```